# With Node.js, how can I redirect random string paths to the home page?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've set up a typical node.js server (vanilla, no express, etc) and its works great. But for my web app, I want to be able to use not a query string, but a simple path to express the user's session ID.

For example `domain.com/GH34DG2` would be served the same as domain.com. I decided to attempt this because I've seen other apps use this format, and it's shorter and nicer looking than a query string. Once the user has been served the page, the client will decipher the path and use it to connect to a specific session.

How can I do this with a basic Node.js server?

When the user types or pastes `domain.com/GH34DG2` into their web browser, I need my server to serve the index page, not try to read the file `domain.com/GH34DG2`, but it still needs to read other paths, like style sheets, videos, etc as usual.

Comment: Assume the most general example of a node server, mine is very modulized and would be more complicated to post here, without really being necessary to the question.

Comment: What part are you stuck at? Whatever handler function you are using should be capable of retrieving the requested path.

Comment: Why dont you set the session ID inside the header and use that inside your route to grab the right data and update the client with the new view?

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Im not sure if Im understanding you right, but the purpose is to be able to give the user the URL `domain.com/GH34DG2` which they can share with friends in order for others to join their session.

Comment: @hofan41 so my handler needs to direct the path to the index before serving, because by default it would try to read the file `GH34DG2` which doesnt exist.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry when the user types or pastes `domain.com/GH34DG2` into their web browser, I need my server to serve the index page, not try to read the file `domain.com/GH34DG2`, does that make sense?

Comment: @CuriousWebDeveloper How do you control the sessions?

Comment: @stdob-- I added a self answer once I figured it out, but to answer your question, the client connects to a socket automatically, and when visiting `domain.com` without a session ID in the url, the server (using socket.io) defines a simple session ID for that user, a session is defined on the server, and the user's URL is updated to be, for example `domain.com/23DH1`, then the user can share that URL, which as shown in my self answer, is treated as the root directory, served, and the client then communicates the wish to join that session through the socket, and communication begins.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was actual embarrassingly simple I realized. All I need to do if check whether the path was missing an extension and then serve `/index.html` (or home.html or whichever one you use), here's my "Check Home Request":

```
function checkHomeReq(path, ext) {
    if (path === "/" || ext == '' )
        path = "/index.html";
    return path;
}
```

Comment: What if the user enters any URL without the extension? For example: `domain.com/23DH2` or `domain.com/23QH1`?

Comment: @stdob-- you mean if the url is an invalid session id? Then they fail to join a session, the url is reset to `domain.com/<valid new session id>` and the user is informed they attempted to join an invalid session.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the request url.

Here's a simple server example I just found on google, I added some stuff to `handleRequest`:

```
var http = require('http');

const PORT=8080; 

function handleRequest(request, response){

    // parse request.url to pull out the session_id
    var session_id = request.url.split('/')[1];

    // do something with session_id
    // serve page/data/whatever

    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
}

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

Comment: But not every path is going to be a session id. There are images, videos, stylesheets, javascript, etc also served. It looks like your example would parse everything as a session ID.

Comment: Yeah, so your parser needs to be able to detect what kind of route it is, which is up to you how you want to implement using regex or some conditionals

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can use something called md5?

in php we have

```
md5(uniqid(rand()));
```

in node.js they have a module for MD5

Comment: I dont think you're understanding. The server has already generated the session ID. Its just that when the user types or pastes `domain.com/GH34DG2` into their web browser, I need my server to serve the index page, not try to read the file `domain.com/GH34DG2`

Comment: sorry, my bad.
why not try to parse the request?

Comment: If you look at my comment to his answer, I dont think his answer does what Im asking about.